# Need help using hide() with on()

Tags: jquery

could somebody please tell me how implement the hide function using on(). I've tried:

```
    $(document).on('hide','selector');
    $(document).on('selector', function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
```

Would like to know how to correctly apply such a function using on();

Comment: on is for handling events.  You just want `$('selector').hide()`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the code?

Comment: simply hide all the matched elements. And also automatically hide elements that are dynamically added to the page (with same selector ofc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function is used to wire up an *event* to something.  You aren't telling it what even to wire up to.  When do you want the element to hide?  Let's pretend you want it to hide when a button is clicked.

HTML:

```
<div id="a">This will hide</div>
<button id="b">Hide!</button>​
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '#b', function() {
    $('#a').hide();
});​
```

If you are just trying to hide the element, not triggered by an event or anything, just call `$('#a').hide();` and it will hide the element.  Of course, change your selectors to work with your HTML.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/Zq756/

Edit:

Interesting.  Do you have any control over the elements that are added dynamically?  If so, I would add a class to the elements you want to have hidden when they're added.  Something like:

`<div class="initial-hide">This div should be hidden when it's loaded.</div>`

Then in your css, add this:

```
.initial-hide {
    dislay: none;
}
```

Then whenever an element is loaded with the `initial-hide` class, it'll be hidden.  See this updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/Zq756/1/.  The Add button will illustrate how the added class will help you out.

Comment: +1 the relevant point here is the **event** bit, hide isn't an event

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to hide an element with the appropriate selector if and when it is added to the page dynamically. Right now I have to apply the $('selector').hide(); script together with the added content.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `on hide` or `on show` event to capture in javascript. What you do is capture the element's hiding and showing and attach a custom function to it.

```
$('element').hide(delay, onHide);

function onHide(){
    //do whatever
}

$('element').show(delay, onShow);

function onShow(){
    //do whatever
}
```